# Pagination in primevue dataview doesn't work

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pagination, primevue

PrimeVue paginator somehow doesn't work with test data. I installed primevue

> yarn add primevue@^3.12.6 --save

imported everything. All components work perfectly, but things like pagination, lazy loading doesn't. Everything loads up, if i change the data, the view changes aswell. However if I try to make pagination (setting rows to 1, and then there are 2 pages) it doesnt change the content. Same with filter, nothing happens. Here are my files

welcome.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel</title>

        {{--    PrimeFlex     --}}
        <link href="https://unpkg.com/primevue@^3/resources/themes/saga-green/theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="https://unpkg.com/primevue@^3/resources/primevue.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="https://unpkg.com/primeflex@^3/primeflex.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="https://unpkg.com/primeicons/primeicons.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        {{--    BoxIcons     --}}
        <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.2/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    </head>
    <body class="antialiased">
        <div id="app">
            <app></app>
        </div>

        <script src="{{ asset('js/main.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

import { createApp } from 'vue'

import App from './App'
import router from './routerList'
import store from '../store/store'
import PrimeVue from 'primevue/config'

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(router)
app.use(store)
app.use(PrimeVue)

app.mount('#app')
```

App.vue

```
<template>
    <AppSiteNavbar/>
    <router-view></router-view>
</template>

<script>

import AppSiteNavbar from '../components/AppSiteNavbar'

export default {
    name: 'App',
    components: { AppSiteNavbar },
}
</script>

<style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;500;600;700;800&display=swap');

    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: 'Montserrat', 'sans-serif';
    }
</style>
```

SiteMenuList.vue

```
<template>
    <DataView :value="items" layout="grid" :paginator="true" :lazy="true" :rows="12">
        <template #header>
            <div class="flex justify-content-between">
                <Button type="button" icon="pi pi-filter-slash" label="Clear" class="p-button-outlined" @click="clearFilter1()"/>
                <span class="p-input-icon-left">
                    <i class="pi pi-search" />
                    <InputText v-model="filters1['global'].value" placeholder="Keyword Search" />
                </span>
            </div>
        </template>

        <template #grid="slotProps">
            <div class="col-12 md:col-6 xl:col-3">
                <SiteMenuListItem :item="slotProps.data" />
            </div>
        </template>
    </DataView>
</template>

<script>
import SiteMenuListItem from './SiteMenuListItem'


import { FilterMatchMode, FilterOperator } from 'primevue/api';
import DataView from 'primevue/dataview'
import Dropdown from 'primevue/dropdown'
import Button from 'primevue/button'
import InputText from 'primevue/inputtext'

export default {
    name: 'SiteMenuList',
    components: {
        SiteMenuListItem,
        DataView,
        Dropdown,
        Button,
        InputText,
    },
    created() {
        this.initFilters1()
    },
    data() {
        return {
            items: [
                {
                    'name': 'Test1',
                    'description': 'desc-test-1',
                    'image': '/assets/images/main_background.jpg',
                    'price': 23311,
                    'category': 'test1',
                },
                {
                    'name': 'Test2',
                    'description': 'desc-test-2',
                    'image': '/assets/images/pizza.jpg',
                    'price': 321,
                    'category': 'test2',
                },
            ],
            filters1: null,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        clearFilter1() {
            this.initFilters1();
        },
        initFilters1() {
            this.filters1 = {
                'global': {value: null, matchMode: FilterMatchMode.CONTAINS},
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

SiteMenuListItem.vue

```
<template>
    <Card class="m-3">
        <template #header>
            <img :alt="item.category" :src="item.image" />
        </template>

        <template #title>
            <div v-text="item.name" class="text-center text-3xl" />
        </template>

        <template #subtitle>
            <div v-text="item.description" class="text-center text-2xl" />
        </template>

        <template #content>
            <div class="font-bold text-4xl text-center">
                {{ item.price }} Ft
            </div>
        </template>

        <template #footer>
            <div class="flex justify-content-center">
                <Button label="Kosárba" class="p-button-rounded"/>
            </div>
        </template>
    </Card>
</template>

<script>
import Card from 'primevue/card'
import Button from 'primevue/button'

export default {
    name: 'SiteMenuListItem',
    props: {
        item: {
            type: Object,
            required: true,
        }
    },
    components: {
        Card,
        Button,
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
    img {
        object-fit: cover;
        height: min(40vw, 20rem);
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The paginator is not going to automagically change your content. All it's doing is providing the UI for paging. You have to write the paging logic yourself with the page event that is emitted. I.e. `@page="dataViewHelper.onPage($event)"`.

The event will provide the page number and more; look up the docs. Tanstack is helpful for querying an api to provide server-side paging.